# Error in Knp Paging

Tags: symfony

I am new in symfony and trying to integrate pagination with KNP pagination.

I am using symfony2.8. I did below code in my controller

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Cmspage');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('Cmspage')->getQuery();

    $limit =   10; //$setting->getAdminPageLimit();
    //pagination        
    $paginator = $this->container->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $this->container->get('request')->query->get('page', 1), $limit);
```

I received below error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher given, called in E:\xmapp_5.6\htdocs\elite\app\cache\prod\appProdDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1423 and defined

Comment: check [this github issue](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/284). Hope this help

Comment: I already used this but no luck.

Comment: could be a cache issue? have you cleared the prod cache?

Comment: Yes I deleted all cache files and tried but still the same issue.